# What is the difference between object reference=classname() and object reference=classname?

Tags: python, python-3.x

And please explain the output of the below code as to why I am getting the output as written in the respective comments section of the code snippet:

```
class person():
  pass


p=person
q=person
r=person()

p.no=1
print(p.no) #output : 1
print(q.no) #output : 1
print(r.no) #output : 1
q.no=2
print(p.no) #output : 2
print(r.no) #output : 2
r.no=3
print(r.no) #output : 3
print(p.no) #output : 2
```

Comment: This might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68645/are-static-class-variables-possible-in-python

Answer (score 2):

`person` refers to the class itself, you could compare assigning like `p.no = 1` with assigning a public static member.

`person()` instantiates a new object of the class `person`. Assigning like `r.no = 3` is like assigning a member variable.